# В первое открытие диалога не работают margins

Tags: android

У меня кастомный диалог со списком.
При первом запуске диалога игнорируются отступы по высоте и часть элементов не видно. **При последующих запусках всё в порядке**.
Совсем не представляю, что может помочь в решении проблемы, привожу кучу разного кода, может, пригодится.
Код лэйаута диалога:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:orientation="vertical"
   >
   <ListView
       android:id="@+id/lvMultiChoice"
       android:divider="@color/backgr"
       android:dividerHeight="1dp"
       android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
       android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
       android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
   </ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

В футер списка кладется кнопка, собственно, обычно её-то и не видно(частично видно):

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnDialogOk"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="OK" 
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/button_grey"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

Создаю диалог я примерно так:

```
dialogMultiChoice = new Dialog(this,R.style.AppTheme_Dialog);
dialogMultiChoice.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_multichoice);
ListView lvMultiChoice = (ListView) (dialogMultiChoice.findViewById(R.id.lvMultiChoice));
View v = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.lv_footer_btn_ok, null);
lvMultiChoice.addFooterView(v,null,false);
dialogMultiChoice.getWindow().setTitleColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.backgr));
dialogMultiChoice.setTitle(Fragment_Filter.adapterFilter.names[id]);

adapMeal = new MultiChoiceAdapter(Samo_Data.MEAL);
lvMultiChoice.setAdapter(adapMeal);
dialogMultiChoice.getWindow().setLayout(lp.width, lp.height);
return dialogMultiChoice;
```

Тема, которая используется при создании диалога:

```
<style name="AppTheme.DialogTitle">
    <item name="android:textSize">16pt</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/black</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
</style>
<style name="AppTheme.DialogWindowTitle">
    <item name="android:maxLines">1</item>
    <item name="android:textAppearance">@style/AppTheme.DialogTitle</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.Dialog">
    <item name="android:windowTitleStyle">@style/AppTheme.DialogWindowTitle</item>
</style>
```

Comment: поробуйте заменить margin на pading

Comment: Не помогает

Answer (score 1):

Не знаю, тема сложная - трудно что-то посоветовать конкретное. Я такое, если честно, вижу в первый раз - чтобы первый запуск отличался от последующего? Мистика какая-то.

Единственное что я вижу здесь так это небольшая сноска в документации:

> The Dialog class is the base class for
> dialogs, but you should avoid
> instantiating Dialog directly.

У вас в коде вызывается напрямую конструктор `Dialog` то есть то чего не рекомендуется...

Я бы посоветовал создать собственный класс потомок от `Dialog` или как сейчас рекомендуется `DialogFrame` - там контроля будет гораздо больше, в частности, при первом создании диалога вы получите колбэк на `Activity.onCreateDialog()`, при втором и последующем вызове `Activity.onPrepareDialog()`.

Comment: Ух. Кучу всего надо переписать. Позже отпишусь, хоть какой совет, а то я совсем в непонятках.
P.S. Вы, конечно, имели ввиду DialogFragment? Или я чего-то не понимаю?

Comment: Да, конечно, `DialogFragment`

Comment: Я переписала. Результат совершенно удивительный. Теперь при каждом открытии прямо на моих глазах диалог слегка "прыгает" и его высота увеличивается на недостающую величину margins. О_О